# One mysql connection available for all forms in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Im starting a new project in Visual Studio as Windows Forms Application using C#. Project has login form, main form and other less important forms. All of them uses connection with mysql. Where should i place code responsible for connecting with mysql server to be able to use it in any form? I dont want to create a new connection in every single form. Any hints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I dont want to create a new connection in every single form.

Well, I wouldn't want the UI classes to access the database directly in the first place... but you *should* be creating a new connection each time you interact with the database, and close it after the operation (probably with a `using` statement). Let connection pooling handle the *real* underlying network connection.

EDIT: See the [MySQL connection pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: +1 although, last time I used the MySQL C# stuff (which was quite a while back) they didn't do any pooling.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: Edited with a link to the docs for connection pooling - so hopefully it's sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a class (call it DataAccess), which would contain all your database access code. You could then reference the namespace of this class in the code for your form and call the appropriate methods to perform CRUD operations.